# Chrome/Javascript memory leak that doesn't manifest in debug mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I am working on a large AngularJS application, that exhibits a memory leak when we switch back and forth between different controllers. To be more precise, we have a menu on the left side of the screen, and the menu options $route to different `.html` partials (that in turn, instantiate different controllers).

To give an example, assume that menu option A leads to partialA.html that instantiates ControllerA, and menu option B leads to partialB.html that instantiates ControllerB.
When the user clicks back and forth between menu option A and B (constructing and deconstructing A and B controllers in turn) we can see from Chrome's "Profiles/Take Snapshot" that memory usage is constantly increasing.

Following the advice from various guides in the Internet, I then did the same test, but this time, I spawned Chrome using...

```
bash$ google-chrome --js-flags="--noopt --nouse-ic --nocrankshaft"
```

...and the memory leaks are now gone - the memory usage remains constant.

If my understanding is correct, this means that the leak is not because of our code, but because of some leaked optimization-related resources from Chrome's V8 engine.

Now, I wish I could just say that to my boss, but obviously, when Chrome's "Black Window" appears because of heap exhaustion, the assumption is that it is my code's fault.

What can I do? Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I also checked with Firefox. After doing 10 round trips between menu options A and B, Firefox "about:memory" window, shows that after "Free memory/GC" , "Free memory/Minimize memory usage", and "Measure", the js-main-runtime-gc-heap-committed and js-main-runtime remain pretty much constant. So, it is definitely Chrome-related (more precisely, V8-related).

Comment: The issue you're describing is being worked on under [issue 2073](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2073). It seems like your only option is to notify the Chromium team that you're suffering from this problem, by starring the issue and if you can, provide more information on the issue by commenting.

Comment: @stevuu: I see... Unfortunately, I can't really submit a bug report on this, as demonstrating it requires tons of code (the controllers contain grids, which are populated with async web services that run inside JBOSS, etc. At least I have a link about the issue now - thanks.